# How can create a password prompt in a batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, passwords, batch-file, input

For a batch thing I'm making, I need to know how can create something like a password system, that hides the text you're typing and/or replaces it with asterisks (*) – so nobody can see what I'm typing in?

How can I do that?

Comment: May be this SO question will give some idea, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it natively within DOS.

You would have to use something like [EditVar](http://www.westmesatech.com/editv.html) and run it like this:

`editv32 -m -p "Enter the password: " PWD`

This could cause an issue with antivirus though because it sees it as a code injection device.

Comment: It IS a code injection device. Albeit an harmless one. Because code injection is needed to manipulate the Env-Vars in this way. And it doesn't work on 64-bit Windows systems ! (At least, not the last time I tried it.)

Comment: I compiled a 64-bit version as well.